# How can I view database table in android studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I tried in this way- http://instinctcoder.com/how-to-browse-android-studio-emulator-sqlite-database/
but I can not find any folder. It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). It's very easy to implement and all you need is Google Chrome to browse your SQLite database.

> Stetho is a sophisticated debug bridge for Android applications. When enabled, developers have access to the Chrome Developer Tools feature natively part of the Chrome desktop browser. Developers can also choose to enable the optional dumpapp tool which offers a powerful command-line interface to application internals.
>
> **Database Inspection -
> SQLite databases can be visualized and interactively explored with full read/write capabilities.**

Answer (score 1):

Besides Stetho you can also use adb!

You can from the terminal:

```
adb shell
```

Than go to your apps folder using `cd`

```
cd data/data/your.app.packagename/database
```

Than you can use sqlite command in your database's file to see it, query it, etc.

A few useful sqlite commands [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-sqlite3-basic-commands/).

The device must be rooted in order to do this (for example, the emulator..).

If you don't have adb command in your terminal path, you can find it on Android SDK installation folder and inside platform-tools folder.